# Mysql restore file .dump database

Tags: mysql

I execute the command : mysql -u user -p -h localhost bd_new < bd_dump.dump. Dont restore the bd and dont show error message.
I use other code: mysql -u root -p bd_new < bd_dump.dump and it happens like previus one.
The trouble are a .dump?

Comment: Linux or windows? does bd_new exist?  Did you check the first few rows in dump file for validity?

Comment: Linux, the bd_new exist and checked the dump file